# SSRS - Get the ReportItem!____.Name of the current item (textbox or column)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I have a big report with 100+ columns named 'Column001', 'Column002' etc etc.

These columns hide depending on whether there is any data or not, and I'd like to have the last column have a right side border.

So I could do something like (in pseudocode)

> = IIF(COUNT(ReportFields!Columns.Values) = CINT(RIGHT([CurrentReportItem].Name,3)), RIGHT_BORDER, NO_BORDER)

Is there any way to get the current item (ReportItem!) so that I can get it's name?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the query then you can modify it to return the number of visible rows as a non-displayed new field in the result set and then compare that value at each column to decide if the border should be displayed.

If you do not have control over the query then I think you are limited to a painful series of nested IIf() statements.